# how to build audio streaming in C# httphandler

Tags: c#, http, audio

How to build an audio streaming service in C# httphandler, like [SubterraneanBroadcast](http://streaming.radionomy.com/SubterraneanBroadcast).

The following code only play a song, but i want to keep playing.

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        //context.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store";
        string filePath = @"D:\projects2017\Radio\App_Data\song.mp3";
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at Streamed TransportMode for WCF services. Hope it helps.